# How to set application insights operation_Name from javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-application-insights

I am trying to set the operation_Name property from the javascript client for application insights. But I expect I pass in the wrong property name. Not found any relevant documentation. This has no effect:

```
AppInsights.trackPageView(name, url, { 'operation_Name': 'something' }, measurements, duration);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by 'has no effect'. The syntax looks correct. Are you not seeing any telemetry being recorded, or are you not seeing the custom operation_Name property??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This value is set in the Operation Context which can be modified using

```
 AppInsights.queue.push(() => {
    AppInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer(envelope => {
      envelope.tags['ai.operation.name'] = 'FabrikamResidences';
    });
  });
```